# Is there a train function in Caffe to train a net from c++ codes?

Tags: c++, caffe

Since there is a file by the name of `classification.cpp` in `Caffe` folder and I can classify my input from c++ codes, so how can I train my network from c++ codes?
I have added `caffe.hpp` and I want to know is there a function like this:

`caffe::train(solver, mysolver.prototxt)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read this file:

```
caffe-master/tools/caffe.cpp
```

Train and test are there.